# How to get all requested url on a page using browser.webRequest

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, webrequest

I am developing a Firefox extension. I am trying to get all requested url/requests(image, css, js, ajax, etc calls) on a page using below code in background.js but it consoles only website url not all requests on the page.

```
function listener(details) {
    console.log(details.url);
  }
  return {};
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  listener,
  {urls: ["http://local.m2/*"], types: ["main_frame"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

How I can get all requests of that particular page?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using below code:

```
function listener(details) {
   console.log(details.url);
}
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  listener,
  {urls: ["http://local.m2/*"]}
);
```